# How to identify what is happening during "Other" in chrome profiling tool

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, profiling

I have a performance issue on a page when it is full of data:

[image]

However chrome gives you no detail when it comes to "Other" - so how does one find out what's happening during the 3.5 seconds of "Other"?

There is nothing in the call tree and nothing in the event log

Edit: Question is "how", not "[what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460614/what-does-the-other-category-of-records-mean-in-chrome-timeline-profiling-tool)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "Other" category of records mean in Chrome Timeline profiling tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460614/what-does-the-other-category-of-records-mean-in-chrome-timeline-profiling-tool)

Comment: @JanWillemHuising No I'd already looked at that.  This says "what" the other category means, but doesn't say "how" to identify what's causing it

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the Content Tracing (chrome://tracing) tool. It revealed that in my case the time was spent flushing recorded canvas-related drawing calls to the GPU via Skia (Canvas2DLayerBridge::flushRecording).

[image: Chrome tracing view]

[image]

The categories I enabled were as below, and the entries appeared on the CrRendererMain thread of the relevant renderer process.

`"disabled-by-default-gpu_decoder", "disabled-by-default-gpu.debug", "disabled-by-default-gpu.device", "disabled-by-default-gpu.service", "disabled-by-default-skia", "disabled-by-default-skia.gpu", "disabled-by-default-skia.gpu.cache"`