# Investigate "Other" time in chrome's performance tab

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out why it take so long for my app to do something so I used chrome's performance tool in devtools.

[image: chrome's performance summary]

I found out that half of the time that I wait (don't worry, it takes 11 seconds only because of the profiler) is spent on "Other" and I can't find out what does it means

I tried looking for it online, there is an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460614/what-does-the-other-category-of-records-mean-in-chrome-timeline-profiling-tool) but there is no solution for how can I investigate further and understand what takes so long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "Other" category of records mean in Chrome Timeline profiling tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460614/what-does-the-other-category-of-records-mean-in-chrome-timeline-profiling-tool)

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski I just saw that too, I'm modifying my question

Comment: It is hard to optimize code without seeing it.

Comment: I’m not asking for optimization, I’m looking for a way to do it myself

Comment: You can make a low-level trace via chrome://tracing, look for tutorials on that.