# In Chrome DevTools Performance panel, how can I see which function calls in my javascript code are contributing towards excessive "System" calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Here is a sample of what I am referring to:

[image]

In the Chrome DevTool Performance panel there is no way for me to see what in particular is causing the large amount of System calls.

How can I work out what in my code is the culprit for this behavior? It's a large javascript library that I have written.

Comment: There's a [lot of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173057) under that category, actually, so it's better to use `chrome://tracing` (look for [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+chrome+tracing)) to see what happens inside the system time so you can make a guess about the culprit based on that info.

Comment: [Speed Up JavaScript Execution](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution)