# Use the chrome performance tab to debug js and find that there are long tasks showing that System (self) and System (children) take up a lot of time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frontend

When I use the development project, I found that the white screen time is very long. I debugged js through the chrome performance tab and found that there are long tasks showing that System (self) and System (children) take up a lot of time, and I can't see the specific js function call stack.

Long task summary

[image: 1]

Enter image description here

[image: 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "System" category of records mean in Chrome Timeline profiling tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460614/what-does-the-system-category-of-records-mean-in-chrome-timeline-profiling-too)